Maximize $f(x)=(1-x)^5(1+x)(1+2x)^2$
For which value of $x$ is the product $(1-x)^5(1+x)(1+2x)^2$ a maximum, and what is this value?
This is easy with calculus, but how would you do it without calculus? $f(x)=(1-x)^5(1+x)(1+2x)^2 \geq 0$ exactly when $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, so the maximun is in that range. When $x \geq -1/2$, the arithmetic mean--geometric mean inequality can be brought to bear with five copies of $1-x$, one copy of $1+x$, and two copies of $1+2x$:
\begin{align*}
(1-x)^5(1+x)(1+2x)^2 &\leq \left(\frac{5(1-x)+(1+x) + 2(1+2x)}{8}\right)^8\\\\[0.5em]
&=\left(\frac{5+1+2}{8}\right)^8\\\\[0.5em]
&=1,
\end{align*}
with equality when and only when $1-x = 1+x = 1+2x$, that is, when $x=0$. $f(x)$ has  a higher maximum between $-1$ and $-1/2$ though, and the question is how to find that $x$.
This is problem #278 in the The USSR Olympiad Problem Book, which targeted high school students.


For $-1\le x \le-1/2$, applying the AM-GM inequality:
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&= 15^56^2\cdot\ \left( \frac{1-x}{15}\right)^5(1+x)\left(\frac{-1-2x}{6} \right)^2 \\
&\le 15^56^2\left(\frac{\frac{1-x}{15}\cdot5+(1+x)+\frac{-1-2x}{6}\cdot2}{8}  \right)^8 = \frac{15^56^2}{8^8}=\frac{3^75^5}{2^6}
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $\frac{1-x}{15}=1+x =\frac{-1-2x}{6}\iff \color{red}{x = -\frac{7}{8}}$

@MikeBertrand you’re welcome!

Using Log derivative :
$$ d_{\log}f(x)=\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=5\dfrac{-1}{1-x}+\dfrac{1}{1+x}+2\dfrac{2}{1+2x}$$
$$f'(x)=f(x)\left(5\dfrac{-1}{1-x}+\dfrac{1}{1+x}+2\dfrac{2}{1+2x}\right)=f(x)\left(\dfrac{2 x (7 + 8 x)}{(-1 + x) (1 + x) (1 + 2 x)}\right)$$
$$ x= -\dfrac{7}{8} $$
should be your point. (Wolfram Alpha confirms)

Very good. How would you do it without calculus though?

I'm on it  for a different method   :)

Either I'm losing my grip (possible) or it's harder than it looks.

Without calculus, I'm trying to look at results on polynomial involving max. Newton identities may help but if you authorize derivatives.
